# How to get rails ajax to recognize that a date was updated and reflect that on the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec

I have a link

```
%a{href: "#", :data => {verifying_link: 'yes', id: link.id, table_row: index}}
  verify_by_js
```

that calls

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-verifying-link]='yes'").click(function(){
    // spinner here
    a=$(this).parent()
    a.html('-spinner-')
    var id= $(this).data("id");
    var row = $(this).data("tableRow");
    $.get("/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row, function(data) {
      if (data.link.verified_date !== undefined) {
       $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="done">Verified</span>');
      } else {
       $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="undone">Unverified</span>');
      }   
    }); 
    //a.html('DONE')
  }); 
});
```

It does get called, I see the -spinner- text but then I always get 'Unverified' in the ui, even though the record was verified (verified date set) in the datbase.  If I actually refresh the browser page however I see the verified date which shows that the update was actually successful.

The controller code is:

```
def verify_link
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  if @link.valid_get?
    @link.update_attribute(:verified_date, Time.now)
  end 
end
```

The network tab is showing a valid `get` for `/verify_link/377&table_row=0`

The piece I feel I am not getting is how `function(data) {
      if (data.link.verified_date !== undefined` works (it was recommended from another question-answer and how that is used by the get call.

Server log shows:

```
Started GET "/verify_link/377&table_row=0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-03 21:52:06 -0400
Processing by LinksController#verify_link as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"377&table_row=0"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Link Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE `links`.`id` = 377 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE `links` SET `verified_date` = '2014-08-04 01:52:06', `updated_at` = '2014-08-04 01:52:06' WHERE `links`.`id` = 377
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `links` WHERE (1 = 1 AND position = 347)
   (44.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered links/verify_link.js.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 347.0ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 46.3ms)
```

which is a little confusing as it references `app/view/links/verify_link.js.erb` but this isn't what is used as it has

```
$ cat app/views/links/verify_link.js.erb 
<%- if @link.verified_date %>
  $("span#verify_link_<%=params['table_row']%>").html('<span class="done">Verified</span>');
<%- else %>
  $("span#verify_link_<%=params['table_row']%>").html('<span class="undone">Unverified</span>');
<%- end %>
```

and that has the text `Verified` or `Unverified` whereas I made the previous one have different text - `Verified OK` and `Not Verified` to make sure and it is those being used in the ui and it is ("Not verified").

Comment: how's the response look like ?

Comment: Added the server log.

Comment: ohh, i just say your updated text. I have answered it in different way but it will work. let me know if you want your answer as per your update.

Answer (score 1):

do this thing in your controller. As i dont see any proper return value on success and error.

```
def verify_link
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  if @link.valid_get?
    if @link.update_attribute(:verified_date, Time.now)
        render nothing: true, status: 200
     else
        render nothing: true , status: 422
     end
  end 
end
```

Do this to the desire javascript file. And change `$.get` to `$.ajax` since `$.get` callback is only called when the request was successful not on failier. Indirectly it also means that, since the DOM is updating (its okay incorrectly) due to the `$.get` callback it means that the request is successful. I am using `$.ajax` as it looks more elegant.

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-verifying-link]='yes'").click(function(){
    // spinner here
    a=$(this).parent()
    a.html('-spinner-')
    var id= $(this).data("id");
    var row = $(this).data("tableRow");
    $.ajax({
      url: "/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row ,
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(r) {  
                $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="done">Verified</span>');
             },
       error: function(r) {
           $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="undone">Unverified</span>');
        },
       complete: function(r) { 
         a.html('DONE');
     }

    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot.  The only issue is that I have the same problem as when the js was separate - I always end up with 'Unverified' even when the record was verified ok.